# Classic asp (vb6) application crashes with 100% CPU usage

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, crash-dumps

I'm having trouble with an old legacy app that recently started crashing. I'm trying to investigate the DebugDiag analysis, but don't have much luck. Either there is a sql query that locks and somehow the calling thread doesn't die away? Then again callstack points to oledb32!CImpIErrorInfo::GetHelpFile+a1.

Here's the info from DebugDiag which I think is relevant to this problem:

The following threads in w3wp.exe_*MyApp*_PID_*7572*_Date__10_21_2010__Time_08_43_22AM_*720*_Manual Dump.dmp are making a database operation using ADO.

The call to MSADO15!CERRORLOOKUP::GETHELPINFO originated from oledb32!CImpIErrorInfo::GetHelpFile+a1

...clip...clip...

Thread 17 - System ID 4160
Entry point   msvcrt!_endthreadex+2f 
Create time   21.10.2010 0:08:16 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:11:22.781 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:27:49.953

This thread is making a database operation using ADO.

The call to MSADO15!CERRORLOOKUP::GETHELPINFO originated from oledb32!CImpIErrorInfo::GetHelpFile+a1

Function   Source 
ntdll!GetUILangID+31
ntdll!LdrpSearchResourceSection_U+186
ntdll!LdrFindResource_U+18
kernel32!FindResourceExW+65
user32!LoadStringOrError+31
user32!LoadStringW+18
msado15!FetchInfo+ba
msado15!CErrorLookup::GetHelpInfo+1e
oledb32!CImpIErrorInfo::GetHelpFile+a1
msvbvm60!ExecProj::SetModuleCount+a
msvbvm60!CEcProjTypeComp::Release+4
msvbvm60!RcmConstructModuleInstance+8f
oleaut32!DispCallFunc+16a
msvbvm60!VBStrToLong+cf
msvbvm60!FileOutString+bb
msvbvm60!_*vbaPrintObj+51

MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+8ad3

MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+accb

MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+af8c

MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+a7de

MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+7b51

MyApp!DllCanUnloadNow+212e

oleaut32!DispCallFunc+16a

msvbvm60!VBStrToLong+cf

msvbvm60!FileOutString+bb

msvbvm60!*_vbaPrintObj+51
MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+8ad3
MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+7d13
MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+6e64
MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+9097
MSWCRUN!DllUnregisterDesigner+8fa6
vbscript!IDispatchInvoke2+b2
vbscript!IDispatchInvoke+59
vbscript!InvokeDispatch+13a
vbscript!InvokeByName+42
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+234c
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51
vbscript!CSession::Execute+c8
vbscript!COleScript::ExecutePendingScripts+144
vbscript!COleScript::SetScriptState+14d
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::TryCall+19
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::Call+31
asp!CallScriptFunctionOfEngine+5b
asp!ExecuteRequest+17e
asp!Execute+24c
asp!CHitObj::ViperAsyncCallback+3f0
asp!CViperAsyncRequest::OnCall+92
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::STAActivityWorkHelper+32
ole32!EnterForCallback+c4
ole32!SwitchForCallback+1a3
ole32!PerformCallback+54
ole32!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+159
ole32!CObjectContext::DoCallback+1c
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::DoWork+12d
comsvcs!CSTAThread::DoWork+18
comsvcs!CSTAThread::ProcessQueueWork+37
comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+190
msvcrt!_endthreadex+a3
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34

...clip...clip...

Client connection from 194.241.111.228:26238 to 81.175.250.2:80
Host Header   81.175.250.2:80 
GET request for   /MyApp/netk.asp 
HTTP Version   HTTP/1.1 
SSL Request   False 
Time alive   00:49:33 
QueryString
Request mapped to
HTTP Request State   HTR_READING_CLIENT_REQUEST 
Native Request State   NREQ_STATE_PROCESS

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but I'd start with throwing ProcessMonitor/RegMon/FileMon/TcpViewer from [live.sysinternals.com](http://live.sysinternals.com).  [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Then, if you still get no clues, I'd break out [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), which is always my nuclear option, because the learning curve is so massive.  But, assuming, you learn the commands, you could break on the crash, then walk the stack backwards and potentially figure out where the error is coming from.

And of course, you could just reinstall everything and that will probably solve all your problems.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that windbg will be the next tool to use if I can't find the answer elsewhere. I also know that since I'm not experienced with windbg, it'll be quite a lot of work to figure this on out.